# How do I read this Twitter search page as XML with Arduino?

Tags: xml, twitter, arduino

How do read the page `https://api.twitter.com/search/realtime?q=%40hooperstuart&src=typd` with an Arduino?

I want to be able to read the XML only, like I can with the Twitter client example sketch. I'm just not sure how to use it with different pages.

Basically I want to be able to 'ring a bell' or 'light an LED' over an Arduino Ethernet shield when people tweet me.

I'm just not so sure how to view my mentions as XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your mentions require OAuth authorization and aren't compatible with RSS feed readers as a result. They are available in XML format if you use the API to obtain them. See [this](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/mentions) for more info